# What's the difference between popping a view controller, dismissing a view controller, and using an unwind segue?

Tags: ios, segue, viewcontroller

I was wondering if anyone could explain when is the ideal time to use a segue and what's the difference between poppping and dismissing view controllers than using unwind segues?

Answer (score 5):

When you present a view controller you replace it with the previous one. and when you push a view controller you create a stack of view controllers.

So pop deals with a stack of view-controllers it will remove the view-controllers one by one from stack.

Dismiss deals with only single view-controller it will remove the current view-controller from memory.

Unwind segue can be used to navigate back through push, modal or popover segues, On top of that you can actually unwind through not only one but a series of push/modal/popover segues, e.g. "go back" multiple steps in your navigation hierarchy with a single unwind action.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `segue`  like thing then you have to maintain this in storyboard thing where push & pop is based on `UINavigationController` where no need worry about maintaining segues in storyboard, also you can get familier with XIB's

**PresentViewcontroller**

> presentViewController is a method of the UIViewController
>   class you use to present a modal view controller.

**PushViewcontroller**

> A UINavigationController is a subclass of UIViewController that
>   manages a stack of view controllers and adds a back button etc.  From
>   UINavigationController you can push a new controller, and later pop
>   it, so to go back to the previous one & controllers in a navigation
>   controller will just build a sequence from left to right.